# Using the CodeIgniter HTML Table Class, how can I add additional columns?

Tags: html, codeigniter, html-table

Adding rows seems to be easy enough, but I want to add columns to my data that have checkboxes so you can "edit" or "delete" that row.

Any CI friendly way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Manually set your headings and columns inserting whatever you need in your last column like so...

```
$this->table->set_heading('Heading One', 'Heading Two', ... , 'Links'); //set your headings

foreach($data_rows as $row) { //set your rows here

    // first build links for this row assuming you need the urls to
    // look like 'http://domain/index.php/controller/{action}/{id}
    $links  = anchor('controller/edit/'.$row->id ,'Edit');
    $links .= anchor('controller/delete/'.$row->id , 'Delete');

    $this->table->add_row(
        $row->heading_one,
        $row->heading_two,
        ...,
        $links,   //add the links you created to the last row, corresponding to your 'Links' Header
    );
}

echo $this->table->generate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **Error in code : Cannot use object of type mysqli as array in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.0.6\application\views\admin.php on line 8**
<?php 
 $table_property = array('table_open' => '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="table table-hover">');
  $this->table->set_heading('#Id','Username','Password','Name','Edit','Delete');
  $this->table->set_template($table_property);
  $new=$this->db->query("select * from tbl_admin");

  foreach($new as $row) {
  $links  = anchor('admin/edit/'.$row['User_ID'] ,'Edit');
  $links .= anchor('admin/delete/'.$row['User_ID'] , 'Delete');


$this->table->add_row(
    $row->User_ID,
    $row->Username,
    $row->Password,
    $row->Full_Name,
    $links
    );
}
echo $this->table->generate();
```

?>

Comment: Can you explain a bit your code? (add some text to your answer) How this code solves the OP problem? What the code does?